# Tiff or Exif tag for BGRA

Tags: image, tiff, exif, rgba

I'm saving a BGRA image in a TIFF formatted file.
I need to save the data as-is without manipulation for recording and analysis purposes.

What tags do I need to set to tell the TIFF viewers that the data is stored as BGRA instead of the default RGBA ?
Currently image viewers just read the data as RGBA, and obviously all the colors are getting mangled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIFF: The specs say you can't:

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf

Page 37: For PlanarConfiguration = 1, the components are stored in the indicated order: first Red, then Green, then Blue.

EXIF: Use tag `ComponentsConfiguration`

http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF

Page 33. You probably want something as 6 5 4 0 for tag number 37121

Comment: Interesting.. That's for compressed data, do i need to set a compression type?

Comment: I would keep the compression type to none (thus, not setting). If ComponentsConfiguration is ignored then, you can't do what you want to do.